# Use order on a single column data frame

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

How do I sort a data.frame with one column?

I'm using the following:

```
> set.seed(456)
> df1 <- data.frame(col1 = runif(10))
> class(df1)
[1] "data.frame"
> df1 <- df1[order(df1$col1),]
> class(df1)
[1] "numeric"
```

However if I add a blank column things work fine:

```
> set.seed(456)
> df1 <- data.frame(col1 = runif(10))
> df1$dummy <- NA
> class(df1)
[1] "data.frame"
> df1 <- df1[order(df1$col1),]
> class(df1)
[1] "data.frame"
> df1 
         col1 dummy
7  0.08243274    NA
1  0.08955160    NA
2  0.21051232    NA
9  0.23750327    NA
8  0.28552695    NA
6  0.33195997    NA
10 0.38523617    NA
3  0.73295527    NA
5  0.78839789    NA
4  0.85213354    NA
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156448/how-can-i-sort-a-data-frame-with-only-one-column-without-losing-rownames/13156498#13156498 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894246/how-to-sort-a-data-frame-in-r/6894362#6894362

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add `drop=FALSE` and it will work with most of the cases.  The default option for `[` is `drop=TRUE`

```
 df1[order(df1$col1),, drop=FALSE]
```

In the help page for ?`[`, the default arguments can be found in the 'Usage'

```
 x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]
```

and the description for `drop` as

> drop: For matrices and arrays.  If ‘TRUE’ the result is coerced to
>             the lowest possible dimension (see the examples).  This only
>             works for extracting elements, not for the replacement.  See
>             ‘drop’ for further details.

Answer (score 2):

With the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package, you don't need the `drop = FALSE`:

```
library(data.table)
setorder(setDT(df1), col1)
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df1
>           col1
>  1: 0.08243274
>  2: 0.08955160
>  3: 0.21051232
>  4: 0.23750327
>  5: 0.28552695
>  6: 0.33195997
>  7: 0.38523617
>  8: 0.73295527
>  9: 0.78839789
> 10: 0.85213354
> ```

Or directly on a dataframe without converting to a `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setorder(df1, col1)
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df1
>          col1
> 7  0.08243274
> 1  0.08955160
> 2  0.21051232
> 9  0.23750327
> 8  0.28552695
> 6  0.33195997
> 10 0.38523617
> 3  0.73295527
> 5  0.78839789
> 4  0.85213354
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- arrange(df1, col1)
class(df1)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to split the sorting operation for the sake of resources optimization and code readability:

```
> positions <- order(df$col1)
# if you want to create a rank: positions <- order(df$col1, decreasing = TRUE)
# and then apply the order without modifying the dataframe
> sorted_df <- df[positions,]
```