# Subset ordered components and relative variable names

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
              PC1         PC2          PC3          PC4          PC5
TGFBI     0.05105828  0.04259313  0.001931321 -0.014739818 -0.023630707
OLFM4    -0.01093027 -0.07768484 -0.056874220 -0.011045101 -0.009762945
CD177    -0.03543697 -0.05385507 -0.073857334  0.024278031  0.009186970
LCN2     -0.01539785 -0.07883489 -0.036711308  0.014314281 -0.010042372
CEACAM8  -0.01130204 -0.08092082  0.004004276 -0.003607281 -0.008600472
```

This is the output of `myPCAdf$rotation`. I would like to sort each PC using abs values and then I would like to subset the top n-genes. If I perform:

```
data.frame(sort(abs(myPCAdf$rotation[,"PC4"]), decreasing=TRUE)[1:50])
```

I obtain the list of values loosing the name of the genes. 
Can anyone help to obtain a data.frame containing two columns for each PC: one containing the name of genes resulting form the sort of the numerical values in the second column.

Thank you in advance.

Desired output (short example):

```
                  PC1       
    TGFBI     0.05105828  
    HLA-DPB1  0.04843209 
    OLFM4    -0.01093027 
    CEACAM8  -0.01130204
    LCN2     -0.01539785
    CD177    -0.03543697
    .............
```

Comment: I just searched for similar results: wouldn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156448/how-can-i-sort-a-data-frame-with-only-one-column-without-losing-rownames) fit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try also a classical for loop:

```
listed <- list() # empty list

# create a loop for each subset of data.frame 
for(i in colnames(df)) {
 dats <- data.frame(gene = rownames(df), pc = df[, which(names(df) == i )])
 listed[[i]] <- dats[order(abs(dats$pc),decreasing = T),]
}

do.call(cbind, listed)

  PC1.gene      PC1.pc PC2.gene      PC2.pc PC3.gene       PC3.pc PC4.gene
1    TGFBI  0.05105828  CEACAM8 -0.08092082    CD177 -0.073857334    CD177
3    CD177 -0.03543697     LCN2 -0.07883489    OLFM4 -0.056874220    TGFBI
4     LCN2 -0.01539785    OLFM4 -0.07768484     LCN2 -0.036711308     LCN2
5  CEACAM8 -0.01130204    CD177 -0.05385507  CEACAM8  0.004004276    OLFM4
2    OLFM4 -0.01093027    TGFBI  0.04259313    TGFBI  0.001931321  CEACAM8
        PC4.pc PC5.gene       PC5.pc
1  0.024278031    TGFBI -0.023630707
3 -0.014739818     LCN2 -0.010042372
4  0.014314281    OLFM4 -0.009762945
5 -0.011045101    CD177  0.009186970
2 -0.003607281  CEACAM8 -0.008600472
```

Comment: Perfectly my desired output. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Are you sure this is the output you need? Data in wide format is rarely useful. Plus observations in this data set conflates across genes and PC, conflicting with input data. Consider long format.

Answer (score 1):

An idea via base R is to split every column, convert the rownames to column, sort and bind them back together, i.e.

```
do.call(cbind, 
       lapply(split.default(df, seq(ncol(df))), function(i){
                               i$rn <- rownames(i);
                               rownames(i) <- NULL; 
                               i[order(abs(i[1]), decreasing = TRUE),]; })
       )
```

which gives,

> ```
>         1.PC1    1.rn       2.PC2    2.rn        3.PC3    3.rn        4.PC4    4.rn        5.PC5    5.rn
> 1  0.05105828   TGFBI -0.08092082 CEACAM8 -0.073857334   CD177  0.024278031   CD177 -0.023630707   TGFBI
> 3 -0.03543697   CD177 -0.07883489    LCN2 -0.056874220   OLFM4 -0.014739818   TGFBI -0.010042372    LCN2
> 4 -0.01539785    LCN2 -0.07768484   OLFM4 -0.036711308    LCN2  0.014314281    LCN2 -0.009762945   OLFM4
> 5 -0.01130204 CEACAM8 -0.05385507   CD177  0.004004276 CEACAM8 -0.011045101   OLFM4  0.009186970   CD177
> 2 -0.01093027   OLFM4  0.04259313   TGFBI  0.001931321   TGFBI -0.003607281 CEACAM8 -0.008600472 CEACAM8
> ```

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` solution could look like follows:

```
f <- structure(list(PC1 = c(0.05105828, -0.01093027, -0.03543697, 
                           -0.01539785, -0.01130204), 
                    PC2 = c(0.04259313, -0.07768484, -0.05385507, 
                            -0.07883489, -0.08092082), 
                    PC3 = c(0.001931321, -0.05687422, -0.073857334, 
                            -0.036711308, 0.004004276), 
                    PC4 = c(-0.014739818, -0.011045101, 0.024278031, 
                            0.014314281, -0.003607281), 
                    PC5 = c(-0.023630707, -0.009762945, 0.00918697, 
                            -0.010042372, -0.008600472)), 
               class = "data.frame", 
               row.names = c("TGFBI", "OLFM4", "CD177", "LCN2", "CEACAM8"))

## first transfrom row names to a column
ft <- f %>% rownames_to_column(f)

## then loop through all PC columns and arrange by abs(.)
map(names(ft)[-1], 
    ~ ft %>% arrange(desc(abs(!!rlang::sym(.x)))) %>% 
    select(rowname, !!rlang::sym(.x)))
```

If you want to just have top 10 (say) rows, add `%>% slice(1:10)`

**Output**

```
[[1]]
  rowname         PC1
1   TGFBI  0.05105828
2   CD177 -0.03543697
3    LCN2 -0.01539785
4 CEACAM8 -0.01130204
5   OLFM4 -0.01093027

[[2]]
  rowname         PC2
1 CEACAM8 -0.08092082
2    LCN2 -0.07883489
3   OLFM4 -0.07768484
4   CD177 -0.05385507
5   TGFBI  0.04259313

[[3]]
  rowname          PC3
1   CD177 -0.073857334
2   OLFM4 -0.056874220
3    LCN2 -0.036711308
4 CEACAM8  0.004004276
5   TGFBI  0.001931321

[[4]]
  rowname          PC4
1   CD177  0.024278031
2   TGFBI -0.014739818
3    LCN2  0.014314281
4   OLFM4 -0.011045101
5 CEACAM8 -0.003607281

[[5]]
  rowname          PC5
1   TGFBI -0.023630707
2    LCN2 -0.010042372
3   OLFM4 -0.009762945
4   CD177  0.009186970
5 CEACAM8 -0.008600472
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider reshaping data to long format, the usual structure for most data science operations (aggregating, data merging, statistics testing, graphing, modeling, etc.). No loops needed:

```
# RESHAPE WIDE TO LONG
rdf <- reshape(df, varying = list(names(df)[-ncol(df)]), times = names(df)[-ncol(df)],
               v.names = "value", timevar = "PC", 
               new.row.names = 1:1E5, direction = "long")

# ORDER BY INDICATOR AND VALUE COLUMNS
rdf <- with(rdf, rdf[order(rev(PC), abs(rdf$value), decreasing=TRUE), ])

# RE-ASSIGN id AS SEQUENCE COLUMN
rdf$id <- with(rdf, ave(value, PC, FUN=seq_along))
row.names(rdf) <- NULL
```

**Output**

```
rdf

#       gene  PC        value id
# 1    TGFBI PC1  0.051058280  1
# 2    CD177 PC1 -0.035436970  2
# 3     LCN2 PC1 -0.015397850  3
# 4  CEACAM8 PC1 -0.011302040  4
# 5    OLFM4 PC1 -0.010930270  5
# 6  CEACAM8 PC2 -0.080920820  1
# 7     LCN2 PC2 -0.078834890  2
# 8    OLFM4 PC2 -0.077684840  3
# 9    CD177 PC2 -0.053855070  4
# 10   TGFBI PC2  0.042593130  5
# 11   CD177 PC3 -0.073857334  1
# 12   OLFM4 PC3 -0.056874220  2
# 13    LCN2 PC3 -0.036711308  3
# 14 CEACAM8 PC3  0.004004276  4
# 15   TGFBI PC3  0.001931321  5
# 16   CD177 PC4  0.024278031  1
# 17   TGFBI PC4 -0.014739818  2
# 18    LCN2 PC4  0.014314281  3
# 19   OLFM4 PC4 -0.011045101  4
# 20 CEACAM8 PC4 -0.003607281  5
# 21   TGFBI PC5 -0.023630707  1
# 22    LCN2 PC5 -0.010042372  2
# 23   OLFM4 PC5 -0.009762945  3
# 24   CD177 PC5  0.009186970  4
# 25 CEACAM8 PC5 -0.008600472  5
```